# Weak convergence problem

Tags: functional-analysis, weak-convergence

Let $\Omega$ ∈ $\mathbb{R}^d$ be a bounded set and $d\ge$ 1. Consider function sequence $f_n ∈ L_3(\Omega)$ such that,

$$f_n \to f\mbox{ weakly in }  L_2(\Omega)\mbox{ and }  \|f_n\|_{L_3(\Omega)} \le M$$
for set constant $M$. We additionally know that,
$$ \|f_n\|_{L_2 (\Omega)} \to \|f\|_{L_2 (\Omega)} $$
Show that,
$$ \|f_n - f \|_{L_p(\Omega)} \to 0\mbox{ for  every } p \in [2,3)   $$

Whether limit function $f$ have to be an element of $ L_3(\Omega) $ ?

Thank for help.

Comment: If you show that $f_n(x)\to f(x)$ a.e then you can use the bounded convergence theorem http://www.jstor.org/stable/2319009?seq=2#page_scan_tab_contents

Comment: From the weak convergence in $L^2$ and the convergence of the $L^2$ norms you get $\|f_n-f\|_{L^2}\to 0$. Now if you assume that $f_n(x)\to g(x)$ a.e, where $f\neq g$, then by the bounded convergence theorem, you get that $f_n\to g$ in $L^2\Rightarrow f\equiv g$. Finally, you get that $f_n(x)\to f(x)$ a.e and that $\|f_n\|_{L^3}\leq M\Rightarrow $ again by the BCT $\|f_n-f\|_{L^p}\to 0,\,\forall p\in [2,3)$, even for every $p\in [1,3)$

Comment: @ChristianRemling But why would we obtain that $f_n\to f$ in $L^3$ also ?

Comment: @ChristianRemling I forgot to say that we use Theorem 2, not Theorem 1

Comment: @Svetoslav: I can only access the first page of the paper, but I think this will work then.

Comment: @ChristianRemling I think you should be able to navigate to page 2 with the arrows on the right side

Answer (score 4):

It's well known that norm convergence in $L^2$ follows from weak convergence plus the convergence of the norms. This gives that $f_n\to f$ pointwise a.e. on a subsequence, and thus $f\in L^3$ by Fatou's Lemma.

Now
$$
\int_{|f_n-f|\le C} |f_n-f|^p \le C^{p-2}\|f_n-f\|_2^2
$$
and
$$
\int_{|f_n-f|>C} |f_n-f|^p \lesssim C^{p-3} ,
$$
since at least one of $f_n$, $f$ is $>C/2$ on this set and, as we observed, the $3$ norms are bounded. So if $2\le p<3$, then we can make $\|f_n-f\|_p$ arbitrarily small by taking both $C$ and $n$ large.

Answer (score 2):

First show the strong $L_2$ convergence. This follows from 
$$
\|f_n - f\|^2_2 = \|f_n\|^2_2 - 2 \langle f,f_n \rangle + \|f\|_2^2 \, .
$$
Just take the limit of each term, using your assumptions.

The $L_p$ convergence for all $p \in [2,3)$ now follows from Hölder's inequality.

Since the sequence converges also weakly in $L^3$, the limit is indeed in $L^3$.

**Added** in response to the comments.

To prove convergence in $L^p$ with $2 < p < 3$, write $p = 2+r$ with $0 < r < 1$ and use Hölder's inequality: 
$$
\|f_n - f_m\|_p^p = \int_\Omega |f_n-f_m|^{2(1-r)}|f_n-f_m|^{3r}  \le \left(\int_\Omega|f_n-f_m|^2\right)^{1-r}  
\left(\int_\Omega|f_n-f_m|^3\right)^r \, .
$$
Since $\|f_n - f_m\|_2 \to 0$ as $m, n \to \infty$ and $\|f_n - f_m\|_3$ remains bounded, this shows that the sequence in Cauchy in $L^p$ and thus converges strongly. The limit must agree with the $L^2$ limit.

To prove weak convergence in $L^3$, use test functions in $L^2 \cap L^{4/3}$, e.g. smooth compactly supported test functions (as suggested in the comments), plus the fact that the $f_n$ are bounded set in $L^3$.

Comment: Why does the sequence converge weakly in $L^3$?

Comment: Weak convergence in $L^3$ maybe comes because you can extract weakly converging subsequences (the norm is bounded). But since they all have to converge to the same limit ($L^2 \subset (L^3)'$), the whole sequence must converge to that limit weakly.

Comment: Weak convergence in $L^3$ is easy because you can test against smooth functions, which is enough because the sequence is also bounded in $L^3$.

Comment: Thank you, see my edited answer.

Comment: Elegant and easy to follow now, thanks!